# How to set spacing between bars while calling barthickness in chart js

Tags: javascript, charts

Hello I am setting a scale like this in my chart.js code

```
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    color: "#fff",
                    zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                    zeroLineWidth: 0
                },
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                barThickness : 30;
                stacked: true,
            }]
```

But in the chart js document it's mentioned in the barThickness section "If this value is a number, it is applied to the width of each bar, in pixels. When this is enforced, barPercentage and categoryPercentage are ignored"

Now I am okay with the barthickness but I need to maintain the spacing between the bars

How do I do that ?